# How to assign action to checkbox in play! for java

Tags: java, html, checkbox, playframework

I have such button on my page

```
 #{if  someCondition}
            <a href="@{MyPage.index(true)}" class="btn">All requests</a>
        #{/if}
        #{else}
            <a href="@{MyPage.index(false)}" class="btn">Filtered requests</a>
        #{/else}
```

Is it possible to make it as checkbox without any button? Action should be executed by checking checkbox. In other words. If checkbox is checked I want to execute @{MyPage.index(true)} and if uchecked @{MyPage.index(false)}.

I've tried

```
 <input type = "checkbox" onchange = "@{MyPage.index(true)}" value = "withMe" />
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template engine on the server side is run when your page is rendered. After the server returns the page back to the user (client side), you can't call the template engine anymore. `onchange` is a JavaScript trigger, you can't mix that with your template commands.

Here's how it works:

```
Client      Server
------      ------
  1
  2   ----->  3
              4
              5
  7   <-----  6
  8
```

1. user navigates to a URL on your site
2. browser sends HTTP request to server
3. server receives the request and maps it via routes to a controller
4. controller does its tricks and calls the view
5. view is rendered using the template engine and a page containing only HTML, CSS (this is generally left out of the page rendered on server and used from a separate static file though) and JavaScript is created
6. server sends above page in a HTTP response back to browser
7. browser receives response
8. browser loads up the page

On server side you can use Java, template engine, poll data from DB, etc. On the client side you can use HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

When the user is clicking checkboxes on the page, there's no connection to the server anymore. Thus in order to invoke the server when a checkbox is clicked you'll have to make a new request.

If you need to say show some extra content on the page when a specific checkbox is clicked, you have a couple of options:

1. Make a HTTP request to server synchronously and load the page again with more content.
2. Make a HTTP request to server asynchronously with AJAX and just use JavaScript to add more content on the page.
3. Load all the data on the page when the first call is made, but only show the relevant bits initially when a page is loaded. When checkbox is clicked, use JavaScript to show new content with rest of data in it.

I'd recommend 2 or 3, since 1 is quite old fashioned and annoying to the user.